# Insert array of links into div with timer with JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, html, timer, hyperlink

I am new to JQuery and I am trying to insert an array of links into a div box with a timer.
this is the code that i have seen used:

```
<div id="link"></div>

    <script>
    var links = [
        "Link 01",
        "Link 02",
        "Link 03",
        "Link 04",
        "Link 05",
        "Link 06",
        "Link 07",
        "Link 08",
        "Link 09",
        ]; 

    setInterval(function() {
        var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * links.length);
        if (i == links.length) --i;
        $("#link").html(links[i]);
    }, 5 * 1000);
    </script>
```

or is something like this more appropriate:

```
<div id="apDiv2"> 
var links = [
     <a href="google.com">google.com</a>,
     <a href="youtube.com">youtube.com</a>,
     <a href="ufl.edu">ufl.edu</a>,
     ];   
</div>
```

this is the style for the div i want the links to go into:

```
#link {
    position:absolute;
    width:382px;
    height:239px;
    z-index:1;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 173px;
    right: 20%;
    top: 348px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/rmAsa/1/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It looks like in the first example you are replacing the link in the #link div with a random value from your array every 5 seconds. If that is what you're after, I don't see any problems.

Comment: i posted the css for the div box

Comment: i want the links to appear in order inside a white div box.....eventually I'd like four div boxes doing the same thing